# handling complex queries in firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm developing a shopping cart mobile application using ionic framework and FIREBASE as back-end . I have a requirement that I need to join JOIN, SORT, FILTER and PAGINATE by multiple data attributes.

Sample data structure is given below.

products : {

```
prod1:{
    name: Samsung-s4,
    type: pro,
    category: Phone,
    created_datetime: 1426472828282,
    user: user1,
    price: 400

},

prod2:{
    name: iPhone 5s,
    type: pro,
    category: Phone,
    created_datetime: 1426472635846,
    user: user2,
    price: 500

},

prod3:{
    name: HP Laptop i3,
    type: regular,
    category: Computer,
    created_datetime: 1426472111111,
    user: user1,
    price: 600

}
```

}

user_profiles : {

```
user1:{
    name: abc_user,
    display_name: ABC,
    email: abc@mail.com
},

    user2:{
    name: xyz_user,
    display_name: XYZ,
    email: xyz@mail.com
}
```

}

I need to query the products using multiple ways. two simple examples given below.

1) Get all products with Pagination, where type is "pro" then join with user_profiles and SORT by created date.

2) Get all products with Pagination, filter by category then join with user_profiles and SORT by created date.

Like above there will be more and more filtering options coming in Eg: price.

My main problem is, I couldn't find straight forward way of doing this using FIREBASE query options. Also I referred firebase util documentation but there also I don't see a way of getting this done.

As far as I see only way to get this done is, do the majority of processing in client end by getting all the data (or majority of the data) in to client side and do the SORT / FILTER / PAGINATE in client end.

But we are expecting thousands of records in these schemas, therefore there will be a huge performance impact if we do the processing in client end !!

Appreciate your expertise/support to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the data structure (as webduvet explained) and tried with firebase-util but failed to achieve what i want. CRITERIA :Products -> Filter By type/pro -> Sort By products.created_date

type: {

pro:{

```
product1: user1,
product3: user1,
```

...

},
  regular:{
   ...
  }

}

firebase-util - angularfire code

```
            var list =  $firebase(new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
                    ref.child("products").orderByChild('created_datetime'),         
                    ref.child('type').child('pro')
                ).select(
                        {key: "products.name" , alias: 'name'}
                ).ref()).$asArray();
```

"products" will have hundred thousand records, so we have to make sure we restrict as much possible in firebase end rather than handling in client end.

Please help !

Answer (score 3):

This has to be done not by queries but by database design. You need to store data in de-normalised way for example:

```
type: {
  pro:{
    product1: user1,
    product3: user1,
  ...
  },
  regular:{
   ...
  }
}
```

the above structure will give you option to query all pro products and retrieve the user id as well. Firebase offer good sorting mechanism so there should not be a problem. The more complex query you require the more complex the data structure will be needed and the more denormalized data you will have.

But as pointed out by @Swordfish0321 sql type of db might suit you much better after all.

Comment: Thanks ! yes, I understand the concept you pointed out. I too tried the same but then again the problem is we need to join type/pro with products to get the product details. Then we need to sort by created_date which is an attribute in products. Firebase does not support JOIN and then SORT. Only option is to use native JavaScript sort after joining the two data sets.

Comment: Pramod, you can use a [NormalizedCollection](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/toolbox/NormalizedCollection/) to join the data and you can sort the first ref passed into NormalizedCollection to achieve the ordereing. @webduvet is still correct here that writing the data in the format you want to read it later is the correct answer, rather than trying to impose SQL relationships on a NoSQL data structure. Work hard on writes to make reads easy.

Comment: @Kato  Hi Kato, I tried with the firebase util with the data structure  webduvet explained. But still i'm unable to get desired result. The main problem is, to sort the products by created_datetime, we have to pass "products" as first reference But then it becomes the master index .. isn't it ? Then I'm getting all the records in products ref, i won't be able to get records filtered by type/pro. As per the documentation then I have to use FILTER option in firebase util. I have main concern over the performance. If the products going to have thousands of records ?? I updated firebaseutil code

Comment: You aren't going to display thousands of records on a client at once; this isn't practical in any ui or useful. Creating a NormalizedCollection with products as the first ref is what you want. Filter by type/pro before you pass the ref into NormalizedCollection. Also, this isn't a discussion forum or a debugging group. If the answers provided can't answer your question, the question needs to be simplified and refined accordingly. Or ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @Kato           I'm not going to display thousands of records ! My point is, if we can't filter "products" straightaway in Firebase, we'll be ended up in processing the records (filtering /sorting) in client end which will be a performance hit when there are huge no of records. As you requested, I'm going to post a followup question with updated data structure and code. Hope you'll attend ! Thanks